# Pygame.init() error: Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault

Tags: python, pygame

I'm using python to develop a small game such as Super-Marie, while I met a problem when excute pygame.init(), below it's the full code.

Using Python 3.7.2 pygame 2.0.1  Ubuntu 16.04

while run in vscode, met the below error:

```
pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.7.2) Hello from the pygame community. 
pygame.org/contribute.html Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault 

Current thread 0x00007f21f417d700 (most recent call first): 
File "/home/zhouyou/projects/FreeTime/marie_adventure/marie.py", line 41 in mainGame 
File "/home/zhouyou/projects/FreeTime/marie_adventure/marie.py", line 56 in <module> [1] 26264 abort (core dumped) /home/zhouyou/anaconda3/bin/python3.7
```

Here is the full code.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import sys

SCREENWIDTH = 822  # Game screen width
SCREENHEIGHT = 199  # Game screen height
FPS = 30  # The time to update the screen

class Map():
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        # load background image
        self.backgroud = pygame.image.load("images/bg.png").convert_alpha()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def map_rolling(self):
        if self.x < -790: # if the map x-axis in (-795-800),means it is still moving in the expeted range
            self.x = 800
        else:
            self.x -= 5

    def map_update(self):
        SCREEN.bilt(self.backgroud,(self.x,self.y))


def mainGame():
    global SCREEN, FPSCLOCK
    score = 0
    over = False  # define the game go on or not
    pygame.init()
    FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()  # control how long for each loops
    SCREEN = pygame.dispaly.set_mode((SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT))
    pygame.display.set_caption("玛丽冒险")  # title

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        pygame.display.update()
        FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainGame()
```

Comment: the console info is below:

```
pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.7.2)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault

Current thread 0x00007f21f417d700 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/zhouyou/projects/FreeTime/marie_adventure/marie.py", line 41 in mainGame
  File "/home/zhouyou/projects/FreeTime/marie_adventure/marie.py", line 56 in <module>
[1]    26264 abort (core dumped)  /home/zhouyou/anaconda3/bin/python3.7 
```

Comment: You should a bug report on pygame's bug tracker. If you're adventureous, you could install gdb and run your game with gdb attached so get more info of what's wrong in your case.